# Когезия и когерентность

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, семантика

Объясните, пожалуйста, как можно проще, что такое когезия и когерентность? И какие средства когезии существуют?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу понравившиеся цитаты из [этой работы](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/kogeziya-i-kogerentnost-osobennosti-razgranicheniya-i-opredeleniya-ponyatiy) (советую посмотреть в ней подробности). Я выделил ключевые слова, отвечающие на вопрос.

> Как правило, считают, что **когезия** обеспечивает внутреннюю
>   лексико-грамматическую связность текста, т.е. связь его элементов, при
>   которой интерпретация одних элементов зависит от других и позволяет
>   адресанту реализовать свою коммуникативную цель с наибольшей точностью
>   и ясностью. **Когерентность** организует части дискурса таким образом,
>   что авторский замысел становится понятным читателю, т.е. реализуется
>   то, что в прагматике называется уместностью. Фактически речь идет о
>   внутренней (структурной) и внешней (прагматической) связности.
>
> Она [когезия — grizzly] включает лингвистические средства (**грамматические, лексические,
>   фонетические**), благодаря которым предложения в тексте соединены в
>   более крупные единицы на структурном уровне. Если мы определяем текст
>   как связный, т.е. логичный, его элементы (слова, предложения,
>   параграфы и т. п.) хорошо структурированы и соединены вместе, т.е.
>   можно сказать, что когезия наблюдается тогда, когда интерпретация
>   одного элемента зависит от интерпретации другого.